# How to include file in Jar through Ant at specific location

Tags: java, ant, jar

I've got an ant jar task:

```
<target name="jar">
    <jar destfile="${generated.jars.dir}/hello-${environment}.jar">
        <fileset dir="${generated.classes.dir}"/>
        <fileset dir="${environment.dir}/${environment}" includes="config.xml"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

How can I force the config.xml file to be pushed to a specific directory in the jar rather than at the root level, say in /database/config.xml or something like that...

PS: The reason for doing this is that I can have a hello-local.jar, hello-dev.jar, hello-qa.jar, etc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use a [`zipfileset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) like this:

```
<jar destfile="${generated.jars.dir}/hello-${environment}.jar">
    <fileset dir="${generated.classes.dir}"/>
    <zipfileset dir="${environment.dir}/${environment}" 
                includes="config.xml"
                fullpath="database/config.xml"/>
</jar>
```

Answer (score 6):

You want zipfileset:

```
<zipfileset dir="${environment.dir}/${environment}" includes="config.xml" prefix="database"/>
```

or:

```
<zipfileset dir="${environment.dir}/${environment}" includes="config.xml" fullpath="database/config.xml"/>
```

Comment: so if I understand you correctly, you're suggesting that after the jar has been created to stuff in the config file through zip?

Comment: No, since the &lt;jar&gt; task extends the &lt;zip&gt; task it supports nesting zipfileset and zipgroupfileset directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Generate EJBs -->
  <javadoc destdir="${ejb.build.dir}/src" classpathref="ejb.class.path" docletpath="${wl.home}/lib/ejbgen.jar" doclet="weblogic.tools.ejbgen.EJBGen" maxmemory="512m" docletpathref="class.path" failonerror="true" additionalparam="-descriptorDir ${ejb.build.dir}/src/META-INF -wls81 -forceGeneration">
   <fileset dir="${ejb.build.dir}/src" includes="**/ejb/*Bean.java,**/ejb/**/*Bean.java, **/ejb/enterprisemanagement/*EJB.java, **/ejb/sitemanagement/*EJB.java, kaas/gateways/rdm/**" excludes="**/agwmgmt/*.java,**/dstprofilemgmt/*.java, **/KaASBaseSessionBean.java,**/com/hns/iag/kaas/rdm/**">
```