# Including a database file in an Jar using Ant

Tags: xml, ant

I am trying to make a jar of a simple inventory program using ant and eclipse.  I have the xml file built, but I need to add something to the buildjar target that will cause ant to include the itemdatabase file - that is currently sitting in the base directory - in the jar.  What I have so far.

```
<target name="buildjar" depends="clean">
    <jar jarfile="${build.dir}/StudioCat.jar">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}">
            <include name="config/*"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${bin.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.class"/>
            </fileset>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="presentation.CreateInventoryUI"/>
            </manifest>
    </jar>

    <copy todir="${build.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
        <include name="config*/**/*"/>
        </fileset>
        </copy>

        </target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to how you included 'config' directory and its contents.

```
<fileset dir="${basedir}">
  <include name="config/*"/>
  <include name="itemdatabase"/> <!-- To include itemdatabase -->
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You use the .jar task (as you're already doing):

- http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html

2) You'd commonly have several subfolders under "src/" in your project:

```
src/
    css/
    java/
    html/
    images/
    config/
```

3) Your XML would live in src/config (for example).  Your

```
<target name="buildjar" depends="clean">
  <jar jarfile="${build.dir}/StudioCat.jar">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}"
         includes="config.xml"
         fullpath="config/config.xml"/>
    </fileset>
...
```

A couple of links:

- [How to include file in Jar through Ant at specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434651/how-to-include-file-in-jar-through-ant-at-specific-location)
- http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html

Q: Are you using an IDE like Eclipse?