# Ant jar task - Include files not underneath basedir

Tags: java, ant, jar, fileset

I am trying to write an ant target that will create a jar based on a bunch of java files and some properties files, but am having trouble including the properties files the way the project is set up currently.

**These are the ant targets I have:**

1 - Compile the java souce files from the "myjar.src" folder and put the resulting classes into a "myjar.classes" folder. Once this is done copy all non .java files from "myjar.src" to "myjar.classes".

2 - Create the jar using the "jar" command using basedir = ${myjar.classes} and tell it to include everything.

**These are the ant targets I want:**

1 - Compile the java souce files and put the resulting classes into a "myjar.classes" folder. Only .java files are included

2 - Create the jars using the "jar" command using basedir = ${myjar.classes.location} but also include the .properties and .xml files from "myjar.src."

The key difference is I want the properties and xml files from "myjar.src" to be included when I package up the classes in "myjar.classes" using basedir = ${myjar.classes} - How do I include these fies when they are not underneath "myjar.classes"?

**This is the ant target I want to modify:**

```
<CreateManifest title="myjar classes etc"/>
        <jar 
            destfile="${myProject.build.jars.dir}\ta_test_driver.jar" 
            basedir="${myjar.classes}" 
            manifest="${manifest}">
            <include name="**"/>
        </jar>
```

The reason I am not just using a directory one level up for basedir is that none of the other jar creation calls in the project do that, and I am hesitant to change that for just this one. I did try to do that, but had trouble specifying the right directory. (There are other jars that use a similar directory structure, and I don't want to interfere with them either now or in the future.) I was just wondering if these is a better way to do this? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure this out from here: [How to include file in Jar through Ant at specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434651/how-to-include-file-in-jar-through-ant-at-specific-location)

This was my modified ant call in the end:

```
    <CreateManifest title="myjar classes etc"/>
    <jar 
        destfile="${myProject.build.jars.dir}\ta_test_driver.jar" 
        basedir="${myProject.classes}\ta_test_driver" 
        manifest="${manifest}">
        <include name="**"/>
         <zipfileset dir="${myjar.src}" 
            includes="**/*.xml, **/*.properties, **/*.gif"
            />   
    </jar>
```

Notice the **zipfileset** tag.